# Vertically align a div within a table <th>

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table header, `<th>`, that contains a `<div>` with text.  I want to *vertically* align the div such that it is aligned to the *bottom* of the header.  I am having serious trouble doing this even though it seems like it should be easy.  Any help would be great.

i.e.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>T<br>E<br>X<br>T</div>
    </th>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

As you can see, I am making the header text vertical (by adding break tags).  The headers are being pulled dynamically and the lengths (and therefore the heights) vary.  But I need them aligned to the bottom rather than the center.

Comment: Why do you need to use a <div> inside a <th>? Why not style the <th> to look like what you want?

Comment: You should post some of your code because as it is we have to make guesses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<style>
th{
vertical-align:middle}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span>T<br>E<br>X<br>T</span>
    </th>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

This should work.

A div with display:inline might do the trick also.
The display:inline is the trick here.